# Eclipse juno giving error in Suse 64bit

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have downloaded the new eclipse juno and jdk 7. But It is giving error while starting. Here is the ERROR.

**A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002b6312df9c6a, pid=1648, tid=1074792768
JRE version: 7.0_05-b06

Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.1-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)

Problematic frame:

C  [libc.so.6+0x75c6a]  _wordcopy_fwd_aligned+0x3a

Failed to write core dump. en disabCore dumps have beled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again.

An error report file with more information is saved as:

/home/jeshwanth/tools/eclipse/hs_err_pid1648.log.**

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Which Juno file did you download?  Which JDK?  Is there anything of use in the report file it mentions?

Comment: Hello @nitind I have downloaded the one which is present in the link [link]http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/R/eclipse-cpp-juno-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz[link] and JDK for Linux x64 jdk-7u5-linux-x64.tar.gz from [link] http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1637583.html [link]. And yes the report contains the same JDK version I have downloaded. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be related to:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=335086

Try not to use the "Browse" button when choosing a workspace but type in the path to the workspace directly.

Had the same problem solved by avoiding the "Browse" button.

Comment: Thanks @Frank, Let me try :)

Answer (score 0):

You should also need to install Java SE Runtime Environment 7 (JRE 7 (64 bit)) form oracle.com. And also check your eclipse juno is 64 bit version for linux.

Comment: I think because he already has a JDK he does not need a additional JRE.

Comment: @Dahaka In windows environment it is OK, but in Linux environment it is not OK

Comment: Hello @SaiYeYanNaingAye Yes I downloaded for linux 64 bit. output of command #file eclipse 
**eclipse: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0**, dynamically linked (uses shared libs). And yes I have downloaded the JAVA Run time also JRE7 . But still there is some problem.